# Sharing rule for report content

Tags: reporting, sharing-rule

I want to show a report to external community user. I created a report in SF admin side and then exposed it on the community portal. But the report shows all the records. I only want the external community user to see the records which are related to his Account. The community users are assigned a role on the Account level.

Can a apply a sharing rule on user role to restrict the report content and show only those records which are related to his Account?

Comment: How community users you have created with role? what type of licenses you are using for community users?

Comment: License - Customer Community Plus Login. Community user role is default role which is applied while creating a portal user (on Account Level).